# What is wrong with my applet code?

Tags: java, graphics, applet, graphics2d

I am following a tutorial on applets on Youtube.  My code looks exactly the same as the tutorial's does, but the background does not turn pink and Eclipse tells me there are errors in `implements MouseListener` and `g2.draw(line);`  What did I do wrong?  [Click here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dVfZ0P6AAn8) for the video and here is my code:

```
package applets1;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.geom.Line2D;
import java.awt.geom.Point2D;

import javax.swing.JApplet;

public class clean extends JApplet implements MouseListener{

public void start(){



}

public void init(){

    setBackground(Color.pink);
    addMouseListener(this);

}

public void paint(Graphics g){

    Graphics g2D = (Graphics2D) g;

    g.drawString("WAZZUP", 100, 90);
    g.drawRect(100, 100, 400, 400);

    Point2D.Double topLeft = new Point2D.Double(0.0, 25.0);
    Point2D.Double topRight = new Point2D.Double(100.0, 25.0);

    Line2D.Double line = new Line2D.Double(topLeft, topRight);

    g2D.draw(line);

}
}
```

EDIT: The error at `g2D.draw(line);` says `The method draw(Line2D.Double) is undefined for the type Graphics`.  I changed `g2D.drawLine` to `g2D.draw`
I also fixed the `implements` typo.  The background is still not pink, despite the absence of an error and everything else works.  What can I do to fix the pinkness and `g2D.draw`?

Comment: `"... and Eclipse tells me there are errors in..."` -- suppose you *might* want to show us the error messages, no?

Comment: And on a more serious note -- don't do applets or tutorials that teach them. And never draw in a top-level window's paint method and you should almost always call a super painting method inside of your override.

Comment: If you get errors, please show those in your question, as they often explain the problem. Also, you've made some typos in your code, such as `implemets` instead of `implements`.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels why shouldn't I do applets?

Comment: @Caders117: [one reason](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30766338/should-i-migrate-away-from-applets-and-if-so-to-what) and [another](https://www.google.com/search?q=why+java+applets+are+dead)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typographical error. `implements` not implemets:

`public class clean extends JApplet implements MouseListener{`

---

Also you have declared g2D with the wrong type (`Graphics` vs `Graphics2D`).  In other words, instead of 
`Graphics g2D = (Graphics2D) g;` you need to use 
`Graphics2D g2D = (Graphics2D) g;`

Once you make the above change, you will be able to invoke the `g2D.draw()` methods using the various 2D classes as parameters.

---

Also you have overridden the `paint()` method but you have not included a call to `super.paint()` - this should be the first line in your `paint()` method.  Once you do this the background color should be rendered correctly (because it is handled by the base class, `JApplet`)

Comment: And call `super.paint`

Comment: @MadProgrammer Good catch, I'll incorporate that into my answer, thank you.