# What is Safari's planned lifecycle for Silverlight (NPAPI)

Tags: silverlight, safari, npapi

- Chrome has already dropped its NPAPI (silverlight) support
- Firefox has announced it will stop NPAPI support as of the end of 2016 (https://blog.mozilla.org/futurereleases/2015/10/08/npapi-plugins-in-firefox/)
- Edge did not support NPAPI from the start
- InternetExplorer is supporting it untill 2021 (https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/lifecycle?c2=12905)

Are there any official announcements on the Safari front?

Comment: Safari 12.0 has discontinued support for most NPAP plug-ins

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The only thing "official" at this time is that the [Get Silverlight](https://www.microsoft.com/getsilverlight/get-started/install/default.aspx) page now cites 31 Dec 2016 as the end of support for Silverlight in Safari. However, as I noted in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34965558/silverlight-on-mac-beyond-2016-is-out-of-browser-oob-an-option) it remains unclear if that date was set by Microsoft, or by Apple planning the end of NPAPI support.

**Update June 2016:**

On the [WebKit blog](https://webkit.org/blog/6589/next-steps-for-legacy-plug-ins/) the Safari team has announced that

> When Safari 10 ships this fall, by default, Safari will behave as
>   though common legacy plug-ins on users’ Macs are not installed.

The goal is to steer site to use HTML5. However they do say:

> If you can’t replace a plug-in-based system in the short term, you may
>   want to teach your users how to enable that plug-in for your website
>   in Safari.

So the end of any Silverlight support in Safari remains officially unannounced.

**Update Nov. 2016:**

Webkit Release Notes for Safari Technology Preview 17 [state](https://webkit.org/blog/7071/release-notes-for-safari-technology-preview-17/):

> Removed NPAPI Plug-in support from .safariextz Safari Extensions

but a date for mainstream release is not given. End of 2016 seems plausible.

**Update Jan. 2017**

From my testing Safari has not yet (1/11) been updated to include the loss of NPAPI support which was part of Safari Technology Preview 17. So far as I can see it is anyone's guess what their schedule is.

Firefox ver 52 mainstream release is [scheduled for Mar. 7 2017](https://wiki.mozilla.org/RapidRelease/Calendar) and according to [here](https://www.fxsitecompat.com/en-CA/docs/2016/plug-in-support-has-been-dropped-other-than-flash/) and the [bug tracker](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1269807). That is the last one to support NPAPI. This sure looks like the end of the road for Silverlight on Mac, unless you move to the ESR release v 52.x of Firefox, which will keep it available for a while. My reading of the ESR release schedule is that it may go to Q1 2018, but interpret that for yourself.

**Update Mar. 27, 2017**

Safari 10.1 was [released](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/releasenotes/General/WhatsNewInSafari/Articles/Safari_10_1.html) and Safari still supports Silverlight, but it must be enabled with each use.

Comment: Is there any update from Apple regarding NPAPI support after March? AFAIK High Sierra still supports NPAPI. Checked on Beta

Comment: **Update Jan 26, 2018** Running Safari 11.0.3 and it apparently still supports Silverlight. (It's the only browser that runs the time-tracking app I have to use for work)

Comment: Support for NPAPI plugins (with the (strange) exception of Flash) has been pulled in the latest Safari Tech Preview (Release 52), so presumably the same will happen in Safari in the near future. https://developer.apple.com/safari/technology-preview/release-notes/.

Comment: Safari 12, released on 2018-09-17 "Removed support for running legacy NPAPI plug-ins other than Adobe Flash." according to [What’s New in Safari](https://developer.apple.com/safari/whats-new/).